# How to fix an unknown key error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I have:

```
    @like = Like.find(:product_id => params[:id].to_i, :user_id => current_user.id, :liked => "Yes")
    @like.destroy
```

The Like table is:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :liked, :product_id, :user_id
end
```

However when I try to run this I get an error saying Unknown key: product_id.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Similar to @yosep's answer... You could also use: `@like = Like.find(:all, conditions: {:product_id => params[:id].to_i, :user_id => current_user.id, :liked => "Yes"}).first`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@like = Like.where(:product_id => params[:id].to_i, :user_id => current_user.id, :liked => "Yes").first
@like.destroy if @like
```

The find method you are using takes in IDs for the objects.

Answer (score 0):

`find` expects the primary id, but `find_by` allows you to specify other values, so you can say:

```
find_by(:product_id => params[:id].to_i, :user_id => current_user.id, :liked => "Yes")
```

It returns a single record which matches the conditions, equivalent to `where(...).take`, per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html